# Call native swift function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

I am sorry, if this question was already asked, but all the answers I could find are for complicated solutions.

I have a viewController, which is webView. I added `WKWebView`, to my view from WebKit library, and opened simple url. Inside of my ViewController, I have a native function called `showAd`.
When the user press the button, which was implemented in javascript, it show call `showRewardsAd`. I set the break point to the userContentController, however, it never goes there.

```
func showAd(){
   print("invoked")
}
extension WFWebViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler{
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "showRewardsAd"{
            self.showRewards()
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("test", completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to simply allow this function to be called from javascript part. As I know, if I want to call javascript function in swift, I simply have to say:

```
 webview.addJavascriptInterface('javascript: function_name();')
```

However, in my case, I want to do it in reverse order. Call swift function in Javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject your user script inside the webView so you could listen to JavaScript's messages when they are posted.

Firstly, you will need to initialize the webView's config and preferences, to allow javaScript:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
config.preferences = preferences
```

Now, you need to inject your script to listen for the click events from the webView:

```
let userController = WKUserContentController()
let javaScript = "showRewardsAd = function() {\n" + "window.webkit.messageHandlers.adClicked.postMessage(); }"
let script = WKUserScript(source: javaScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
userController.addUserScript(script)
userController.add(self, name: "adClicked")
config.userContentController = userController
```

Now instantiate your webView with the configuration from above:

`self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)`

Now, your `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol is implemented correctly:

```
extension WFWebViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler{
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "showRewardsAd"{
            self.showRewards()
            print("Ad is being shown.")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you. I assumed that `showRewardsAd` is implemented in the JavaScript on the website which you're accessing.